# Cocoa control for lists?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

Is there any Cocoa control equivalent to WPF's itemscontrol? I have been using a single column, view based NSTableView but can't seem to get individual rows to size to fit their content, or even to get different height rows (all views are sized to be as tall as the tallest one).
More generally speaking, is there any way of getting views to size to fit their content? I have been using constraints, but seem to only be able to make views size according to their container's size.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NSTableViewDelegate` and it's `-tableView:heightOfRow:` method to specify the individual row height.